# Too many redirects error on safari while accessing a CAS protected resource

Tags: redirect, safari, cas

I have been trying to access an image that is CAS protected. I am trying to load the image after document.ready (by changing the image source). 
The problem is that I am getting a too many redirects error in the console when I use this method.
However, if I directly put the image source in the address bar itself, the resource becomes accessible.
The problem is happening only on safari v 5.1
Any idea why its happening?

Comment: Did you ever track this down?  I saw another case somewhere that mentioned that they could see multiple CAS tickets getting created in the Catalina.out file when this happens.  Just wondered if maybe you noticed the same behavior?